# TinyMCE Issues one certain Domains

Tags: tinymce

I have built a CMS using TinyMCE and I have used this CMS across 3 different website domains already using GoDaddy hosting.  For some reason, TinyMCE isn't working on this new domain I am using (and still using GoDaddy to host this domain).  All I do is copy the current CMS files and paste them into the website domain and that has worked across the first 3 websites, but this fourth one just breaks.  I tried reuploading the files and everything.  Finally I tried just referencing the tiny_mce.js from one of my other sites and that makes TinyMCE finally show up. What would be the reasoning behind tinyMCE working on the first 3 and not the newest one when all the files are exactly identical?

Comment: do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: I get `p is not a constructor`

Comment: can you find out at what souce code this error occurs?

Comment: please use the development version and include tiny_mce_dev.js instead of tiny_mce.js - this gives some helpfull hints

Comment: I found out it had something to do with the doc type not being present, but it isn't a problem on some domains. Good practice to have though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it had something to do with the doc type not being present, but it isn't a problem on some domains. Good practice to have though.